# deploy artifacts to a remote server using msbuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have all the artifacts are added to the folder c: \ artefacts in this folder for example 2 project c: \ artefacts \ proj1 and c: \ artefacts \ proj2. I need to copy from c : \ artefacts \ proj2 all such files to the server \ \ 10.77.0.3 \ Proj2 where Proj2 a folder which has a share. if I perform

Program Files (x86) \ IIS \ Microsoft Web Deploy V3 \ msdeploy.exe-verb: sync-source: contentPath = c: \ artefacts \ proj2, includeAcls = true-dest: contentPath = \ \ 10.77.0.3 \ Proj2 then I all copied. but if I write so in msbuild

```
<MSBuild Projects="artefacts \proj2\proj2.sln"
             Properties="OutDir=\ \ 10.77.0.3 \С$\ Proj2;
             Configuration=$(Configuration); "
             ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

system writes that there is no permission to write to \ \ 10.77.0.3 \С$\ Proj2

Answer (score 0):

Why isnt msdeploy enough? MSDeploy was build to transfer files onto web servers.

But OKay, if you want to do it your way than if you have your severs in a domain then check the username TeamCity's agents are being run and verify that this user has permissions on the 10.77.03.

If you dont have your servers in domain then this can be a problem, you could always set permissions to everyone on that directory but i would **not** recommended it.